# Error with modal - Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript, laravel, modal-dialog

can anyone show me what mistakes that I've done?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm badge badge-success"
  data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#ModalAccept{{ $item>id }}">
  Accept
 </button>
```

This is the modal :

```
<div class="modal" id="ModalAccept{{ $item->id }}"
  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <form action="{{ route('car-lending.accept', $item->id) }}"                                                    
     id="formAcceptDireksi{{ $item->id }}"
    </form>
   </div
   <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="submit"
       class="btn btn-sm badge badge-success"
       style="cursor: pointer"
       id="DireksiAccept{{ $item->id }}">Accept</button>
   </div>
  </div
</div
```

And this is Javascript :

```
$("#DireksiAccept'.$item->id.'").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let id = $(this).data("id");
            Swal.fire({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You wont be able to revert this!",
            icon: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
            cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonText: "Accept!"
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    $("#formAcceptDireksi'.$item->id.'").submit();
                }
            })
        });
```

Thanks, hope ur helping me, I'm really confused what mistakes in that code, I added other modal it looks fine

Comment: I'm assuming there is a JavaScript code. Please update your question with adequate information.

Comment: I've edited it, please check JS code

Comment: You are using ```$item->id``` in your jQuery selector. That's wrong syntax.

Comment: Instead of using an id as a selector, use a class instead.

Comment: Okay, what should I change? $item->id is in foreach

Comment: I'm coming up with a solution. Give me a min.

Answer (score 0):

Change your modal to this

```
<div class="modal" id="ModalAccept{{ $item->id }}"
  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <form action="{{ route('car-lending.accept', $item->id) }}"                                                    
     id="formAcceptDireksi{{ $item->id }}"
    </form>
   </div
   <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="submit"
       class="btn btn-sm badge badge-success"
       style="cursor: pointer" data-id="{{ $item->id }}" 
       id="DireksiAccept{{ $item->id }}">Accept</button>
   </div>
  </div
</div
```

Instead of the above javascript you used, use this:

```
$("[id^=DireksiAccept]").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let id = $(this).data("id"); // Get the value of data-id="..."
            Swal.fire({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You wont be able to revert this!",
            icon: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
            cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonText: "Accept!"
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    $("#formAcceptDireksi"+id).submit();
                }
            })
        });
```

This should work, give me a feedback.